# Taylor Series using a while loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, while-loop, taylor-series

I'm trying to approximate cos(x) using a Maclaurin Series. The value of x and error bounds need to be user inputs, and the user needs to see the estimated value and number of iterations required to reach that answer. I'm trying to demonstrate it using x=2 and error<=.001.  With these parameters, my code always returns 8 iterations, and an answer of -.0476. What have I done wrong?

```
function [CosApprox, Numberofterms] = cos_approx(x, E)
    k(1)=1;
    T=1;
    cos_approx(1)=1
    while T>=E
        k=k+1;
        cos_approx(k)= cos_approx(k-1) + ((-1)^(k-1))*(x^(2*(k-1)))/(2*(factorial(k-1)));
        T=abs(cos_approx(k) - cos(x));
    end
    CosApprox=cos_approx(k)
    Numberofterms=k
```

I'm really new to matlab, so I apologize if I've missed something obvious.

Comment: Please, no more calls to factorial.

Comment: Your code is not complete. What is the line `CosApprox=cos_approx(k)` for? Is it outside or inside `cos_approx()`? Are you using recursion here? The math in your intro is unclear. What do you mean by "demonstrate"? As in, how strongly do you want to demonstrate your hypothesis? Are you plotting the error function in terms of x? Here in SO, we deal with programming issue only. You have to nail down your math and be crystal clear with what you need to implement before asking a question. Afterwards, follow the typical [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: Also please comment your code with what you intend to achieve in every section of the code when you ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't return 8 iterations, it returns 513 iterations on my computer and it terminates because we are dividing a very big number, more than 2^(512) in the numerator and another very big number 512! which is evaluated to be Inf in the denominator.

You are  using the wrong mathematical formula.

```
2*(factorial(k-1))
```

in the denominator  should have been

```
factorial(2*(k-1))
```

Just by changing that would give you an answer of -0.4159 while cos(2) is approximated -0.4161.

Now that you figure out what is wrong, you can try to improve on the code in terms of speed and readability.

Remark: Try not to give the same name to a vector and a function, it's confusing.